# Azure functions - How to read form data

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk

How to read **form data** in **Azure functions**? I tried to do it in several ways, but always I get an error, eg.:

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $" {data}");
}
```

Error: `Exception while executing function: Functions.FormTrigger. System.Net.Http.Formatting: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'FormDataCollection' from content with media type 'application/json'.`

I checked request content and I'm getting request as `multipart/form-data`:

```
" ------WebKitFormBoundary47wKq7pk9Fcc4H9J\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\nsdgs\r\n
------WebKitFormBoundary47wKq7pk9Fcc4H9J\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\" _replyto\"\r\n\r\nsdg@sdg.com\r\n
------WebKitFormBoundary47wKq7pk9Fcc4H9J\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"\r\n\r\nsdgsd\r\n
------WebKitFormBoundary47wKq7pk9Fcc4H9J--\r\n"
```

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: What is the type of request content? I.e., whether it is - application/x-www-form-urlencoded, or do you have application/json contents? "ReadAsFormDataAsync" only accepts "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" type of contents.

Comment: @Nirman I tried it and it works, but always get empty result from expressions, like: data["message"]

Comment: Can you try reading - req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result ? This should give you name-value collection

Comment: @Nirman It returns me something like that: http://pastebin.com/vnKsQQCb  :( I think it's strongly related with Azure Functions...

Comment: seems strange! one last go from my side - NameValueCollection col = req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result; return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $" {col[0]}");

Comment: @Nirman I figured out what is a problem. Your first comment was correct... I tested it using Postman and form data were in `form-data` section instead of `x-www-form-urlencoded` section. Unfortunately my header was ignore. Post it as answer and I'll mark it a an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the request contains "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" type of contents, you need to convert the input to NameValueCollection in order to read input:

```
NameValueCollection col = req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result; 
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $" {col[0]}");
```

You can also pass Key string instead of Index which would make the code more readable and self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

In order to read form data, there is the method ReadAsMultipartAsync:

```
data = await req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```